# Difference between semaphore count and operation value which is passed during semop call

Tags: c, unix, ipc, semaphore

On [Beej Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/semaphores.html), There is a statment as follows

"When you first create some semaphores, they're all uninitialized; it takes another call to mark them as free."

Intially i created with semaphore count as 5.

```
#define SEM_COUNT 5
semget(sem_key,SEM_COUNT,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0600);
```

Now as per the above statement from beej guide, i have to intiaize the 5 semaphores to mark them as free by calling semop.

To indicate semaphore as free am passing the sem_op as 1

```
sem_op[0].sem_op=1;
```

Query 1. Can the sem_op value be more than one? For example If it passed as 3, then whats does that mean?

My understanding for query 1 : It is the number of resources(thread or process) that can access the critical section or shared resource at a time.

Query 2. If my understanding about query 1 is correct, then semaphore count which i am passing for semget is the individual semaphores that can be used for sevaral critical sections. If i created semaphore count as 5. Then it means that i can acess the 5 critical sections. The simentaneous resources that can access this 5 critical sections parrallely will be said during semop call. Is my understanding correct?

Note: I am using the implementation done for system V(sys/sem.h)

Reason behind this queries : I confused myself like whether sem_op value as number of semaphores free (or) number of resources in individual semaphores is free.

SAMPLE CODE

```
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEMAPHORE_COUNT 1

void semaphore_wait(int sem_id);
void semaphore_signal(int sem_id);


int main()
{
   /* 1.Getting the semaphore Key */

   key_t sem_key=ftok("key.txt",'S');

   if(0 >= sem_key)
   {
      perror("Error in getting key: ");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("\nSucessfully generated semaphore key. Value %d ",sem_key);
   }

   /* 2.Attaching the key to semaphore */

   int sem_id = semget(sem_key,SEMAPHORE_COUNT,0);

   struct sembuf sem_inp;
   sem_inp.sem_op=1; /*Semaphore  operation: 1:Increment -1:Decrement: Query1: Can this value can be more than 1? what does that means if greater than 1? */
   sem_inp.sem_num=0;
   sem_inp.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

   semop(sem_id,&sem_inp,1);
   /* 3.Utilizing the semaphore on critical sections */

   printf("\n Waiting for semaphore...");
   semaphore_wait(sem_id);
   printf("\n Acquired semaphore...");
   sleep(4);
   semaphore_signal(sem_id);
   printf("\n Released semaphore...");


   return 0;
}


void semaphore_wait(int sem_id)
{
   struct sembuf sem_inp;
   sem_inp.sem_op=-1; /*Semaphore  operation: 1:Increment -1:Decrement */
   sem_inp.sem_num=0;
   sem_inp.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

   semop(sem_id,&sem_inp,1);

}

void semaphore_signal(int sem_id)
{
   struct sembuf sem_inp;
   sem_inp.sem_op=1; /*Semaphore  operation: 1:Increment -1:Decrement */
   sem_inp.sem_num=0;
   sem_inp.sem_flg=SEM_UNDO;

   semop(sem_id,&sem_inp,1);
}
```

Comment: You abstracted some of your code, what is sem_op[0]? you do not define it anywhere... Anyhow, the use of sem_op, providing it is a semop, is wrong. I suggest you read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/semop.html In a nutshell - sem_op means the operation type to be run on the array of semaphores atomically

Comment: @IshayPeled Attached the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1:

The sem_op can be more than one. In that case, that number is added to the permits the semaphore has

Query 2:

You assumption on query 1 is wrong. It is not the absolute number of permits but the addition to the number of those. The meaning of 'semaphore permit' is how many entities can hold that semaphore simultaneously. This means for example, that if you have 5 threads competing on a critical section protected by a semaphore with 3 permits, only 3 will be able to get in simultaneously.

From the manual:

```
The variable sem_op specifies one of three semaphore operations:

    1. If sem_op is a negative integer and the calling process has alter permission, one of the following shall occur:

        *  If  semval(see <sys/sem.h>) is greater than or equal to the absolute value of sem_op, the absolute value of sem_op is subtracted from sem‐
           val.  Also, if (sem_flg &SEM_UNDO) is non-zero, the absolute value of sem_op shall be added to the semadj value of the calling process for
           the specified semaphore.

        *  If semval is less than the absolute value of sem_op and (sem_flg &IPC_NOWAIT) is non-zero, semop() shall return immediately.

        *  If  semval  is  less than the absolute value of sem_op and (sem_flg &IPC_NOWAIT) is 0, semop() shall increment the semncnt associated with
           the specified semaphore and suspend execution of the calling thread until one of the following conditions occurs:

           --  The value of semval becomes greater than or equal to the absolute value of sem_op.  When this occurs, the value of semncnt  associated
               with  the  specified  semaphore  shall  be  decremented, the absolute value of sem_op shall be subtracted from semval and, if (sem_flg
               &SEM_UNDO) is non-zero, the absolute value of sem_op shall be added to the semadj value of the calling process for the specified sema‐
               phore.

           --  The  semid for which the calling thread is awaiting action is removed from the system. When this occurs, errno shall be set to [EIDRM]
               and −1 shall be returned.

           --  The calling thread receives a signal that is to be caught. When this occurs, the value of semncnt associated with the specified  sema‐
               phore shall be decremented, and the calling thread shall resume execution in the manner prescribed in sigaction().

    2. If  sem_op  is  a positive integer and the calling process has alter permission, the value of sem_op shall be added to semval and, if (sem_flg
       &SEM_UNDO) is non-zero, the value of sem_op shall be subtracted from the semadj value of the calling process for the specified semaphore.

    3. If sem_op is 0 and the calling process has read permission, one of the following shall occur:

        *  If semval is 0, semop() shall return immediately.

        *  If semval is non-zero and (sem_flg &IPC_NOWAIT) is non-zero, semop() shall return immediately.

        *  If semval is non-zero and (sem_flg &IPC_NOWAIT) is 0, semop() shall increment the semzcnt associated with the specified semaphore and sus‐
           pend execution of the calling thread until one of the following occurs:

           --  The value of semval becomes 0, at which time the value of semzcnt associated with the specified semaphore shall be decremented.

           --  The  semid for which the calling thread is awaiting action is removed from the system. When this occurs, errno shall be set to [EIDRM]
               and −1 shall be returned.

           --  The calling thread receives a signal that is to be caught. When this occurs, the value of semzcnt associated with the specified  sema‐
               phore shall be decremented, and the calling thread shall resume execution in the manner prescribed in sigaction().

   Upon successful completion, the value of sempid for each semaphore specified in the array pointed to by sops shall be set to the process ID of the
   calling process. Also, the sem_otime timestamp shall be set to the current time, as described in Section 2.7.1, IPC General Description.
```